# JavaScript / jQuery selector value function

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-selector

I have the following function which opens a modal and puts some value into a div. It works but the function looks ugly, I hope for improvements (maybe more dynamic).

```
submitDelete: function() {

    // projects
    $('button[name="removeProj"]').on('click', function(e){
        var $form      = $(this).closest('form'); // closest parent form
        var $id        = $(this).data('id');
        var $title     = $(this).data('title');
        var $createdAt = $(this).data('created-at');
        var $updatedAt = $(this).data('updated-at');
        e.preventDefault();
        if($id != '') {
            $("#prodId").empty().append($id);
        } else {
            $("#prodId").empty().append('-');
        }
        if($title != '') {
            $("#prodTitle").empty().append($title);
        } else {
            $("#prodTitle").empty().append('-');
        }
        if($createdAt != '') {
            $("#prodCreatedAt").empty().append($createdAt);
        } else {
            $("#prodCreatedAt").empty().append('-');
        }
        if($updatedAt != '') {
            $("#prodUpdatedAt").empty().append($updatedAt);
        } else {
            $("#prodUpdatedAt").empty().append('-');
        }
        $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        $('#delete').click(function() {
            $form.trigger('submit'); // submit the form
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript you can do this:

```
var example = someValue || 'fallbackValue';
```

if `someValue` does not have a value, `example=='fallbackValue'`, otherwise it'll be whatever value `someValue` has; You can integrate this in your code.

```
// You can now replace this:
if($id != '') {
    $("#prodId").empty().append($id);
} else {
    $("#prodId").empty().append('-');
}
// With this:
$("#prodId").empty().append( $(this).data('id') || '-') 
// Or just set it directly:
$("#prodId").val( $(this).data('id') || '-')
```

## Resulting in:

```
submitDelete: function() {

    // projects
    $('button[name="removeProj"]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form      = $(this).closest('form'); // closest parent form

        $("#prodId").val(        $(this).data('id') || '-'); 
        $("#prodTitle").val(     $(this).data('title') || '-');
        $("#prodCreatedAt").val( $(this).data('created-at') || '-');
        $("#prodUpdatedAt").val( $(this).data('updated-at') || '-'); 

        $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        $('#delete').click(function() {
            $form.trigger('submit'); // submit the form
        });
    });
}
```

**Instead of `.val()` you can use `.text()` or `.html()` to set the values of other types of elements like divs.*

Comment: interesting I will check this out, I think you forgot ";" after val(...)

Comment: I forgot to mention that .val will not work since `$("#prodId")..` are not forms elements they are regular `div + p Tags`

Comment: The `;` isn't needed, but I do prefer to use them, updated the anders. Also updated my answer with one more line at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```
$('button[name="removeProj"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var button = this;
    var $form  = $(this).closest('form');

    [
     { target: 'prodId', key: 'id' },
     { target: 'prodTitle', key: 'title' },
     { target: 'prodCreatedAt', key: 'created-at' },
     { target: 'prodUpdatedAt', key: 'updated-at' },
    ].map(function(item){
        $("#".concat(item.target)).empty().append(button.data(item.key) || '-');
    });

    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false  });

    $('#delete').click(function() {
        $form.trigger('`submit');
    });
});
```

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) docs here

---

**Update #2**:

If you change your `ids` like this:

- `prodId` -> `id`
- `prodTitle` -> `title`,
- `prodCreatedAt` => `created-at`,
- `prodUpdatedAt` => `updated-at`

Then you code can be changed to :

```
submitDelete: function() {
    $('button[name="removeProj"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var button = this;

        ['id', 'title', 'created-at', 'updated-at'].map(function(item) {
            $("#".concat(item)).empty().append(button.data(item) || '-');
        });

        $('#confirm').modal({  backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        $('#delete').click(function() {
            $form.trigger('submit'); // submit the form
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not wrong to loop through the ID's, but you're now forcing that your ID's must be those names. It might work in this case, but I've run into enough situations where this seems nice, and came back to bite me in the ...

Comment: @Martijn, well, you can use first solution anyway.